# How to use derived columns in Spring Data JPA associations

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `TeamActivity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams_to_activities")
public class TeamActivity {
    @Column(name = "scope_id", nullable = false)
    private String scopeId;

    @Column(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
    private String teamId;

    @Column(name = "activity_set_id", nullable = false)
    private String activitySetId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "scoped_team_activity_id", nullable = false)
    private String scopedTeamActivityId;
}
```

And another entity `ActivitySet`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity_sets")
public class ActivitySet {
    @Column(name = "scope_id", nullable = false)
    private String scopeId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "scoped_activity_set_id", nullable = false)
    private String scopedActivitySetId;
}
```

1. There's no index on any other column besides the PK in both tables.
2. There's no FK constraint creating a relationship between these tables whatsoever. I have no idea why as this is a legacy system.
3. Technically, if I fetch a `TeamActivity` record, I can pick the `scope_id` and `activity_set_id` from it and combine them to form a `scoped_activity_set_id` which would be a valid PK to fetch the corresponding `ActivitySet`.
4. I know that `TeamActivity -> ActivitySet` is a `N -> 1` association

I would like to leverage Spring Data JPA features to create an association from `TeamActivity` to `ActivitySet` such that when I fetch a `TeamActivity` from `TeamActivityRepository`, the corresponding `ActivitySet` is also returned.
I have created an association like this before using a combination of `@JoinColumn` and `@MapsId` but there was actually a single FK to use which is different here where source table has 2 columns I can combine to get the target's key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fully in control of the database, I may propose you create a **Materialized View** with the contents you desire from both tables and handle it as any other table with JPA, i.e, create `@Entity` model and `CrudRepository<MVTeamActivitySet, String>`.

If you are not fully in control of the database, one easy way to achieve it is to simply create a method that internally executes two lookup queries and retrieves the expected model you want. You will still be using using JPA correctly.

Querying two tables and joining desired fields in the code layer is quite common with denormalized DBs, sometimes you want to avoid the overhead of a Materialized View.

```
@Override
public TeamActivitySetDto findById(String scopedTeamActivityId) throws DemoCustomException {
    Optional<TeamActivity> teamActivityEntity = teamActivityDao.getById(scopedTeamActivityId);
    if(teamActivityEntity.isEmpty()) {
        throw new DemoCustomException("teamActivity record not found");
    }

    String scopedActivitySetId =
            teamActivityEntity.get().getScopeId() + ":" + teamActivityEntity.get().getActivitySetId();

    Optional<ActivitySet> activitySetEntity = activitySetDao.getById(scopedActivitySetId);
    if(activitySetEntity.isEmpty()) {
        throw new DemoCustomException("activitySet record not found");
    }

    return TeamActivitySetDto.builder()
            .description(activitySetEntity.get().getDescription())
            .name(activitySetEntity.get().getName())
            .scopedActivitySetId(activitySetEntity.get().getScopedActivitySetId())
            .activitySetId(teamActivityEntity.get().getActivitySetId())
            .scopedTeamActivityId(teamActivityEntity.get().getScopedTeamActivityId())
            .scopeId(teamActivityEntity.get().getScopeId())
            .teamId(teamActivityEntity.get().getTeamId())
            .build();
}
```